# AS3 shared objects that can be accessed by swfs on different html pages?

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

Is there a way to make a shared object that can be accessed by two different swf files on two different web pages? It works locally but when not when I upload the files to a server. How else can two swfs share information, without a database? I'm trying to have a settings panel on one page, and have all other flash files access the settings. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any solution for this?
*To access the same shared object by different swf files...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `localPath` parameter of [SharedObject.getLocal()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getLocal()):

> The most permissive approach is to set localPath to / (slash), which makes the shared object available to all SWF files in the domain, but increases the likelihood of name conflicts with other shared objects in the domain.

Comment: That's what I tried initially, but the Shared Objects still can't be accessed by swfs in different locations. That works locally though.

Comment: that really should work as long as they are hosted by the same domain. 
do you have any examples of it not working?